# a:focus not working in touch devices like iphone, samsung galaxy

Tags: android, css, mobile, touch

I have defined **css** for **a:focus** which is working **fine** in desktops and laptops,but is **not** working in **iphone** , samsung galaxy, other touch devices etc.

Do we need to define any alternative css for **a:focu**s in touch devices.

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: use `a:active` instead

Comment: @BasvanStein, thanks for your answer, I tried that in emulator, it seems working, can you post this as answer please

Comment: Sure, done, nice it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile devices you can use `a:active` as css selector instead.

Answer (score 2):

u may need to write js. ation tap_down tap_up tap_leave.

Comment: Hi String, i would like to go with BasvanStein who has asked me to use a:active, i tried using emulator , and it is working, and I need to check in mobile only after code deployment.Thanks for help